# Test Automation Feature in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode

Do anybody knows what is Test Automation Feature in Xcode4 and how it can be  beneficial???

Answer (score 1):

Using Automation, you can write UI test javascripts to step through your application's UI.

Comment: Javascript strikes me as heavy-duty lifting and unpleasant reading. I intend to give Frank a try for acceptance testing. http://blog.thepete.net/2010/07/frank-automated-acceptance-tests-for.html

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, Frank is one of the good automated testing tool for acceptance testing of mobile applications. But, Frank does not support test automation if the source code of mobile app is not available